# SVG and JS, dynamically clip a specific path by percentage

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a SVG image in a HTML page.
This SVG image is made by a variety of G objects, each one made by many PATH objects inside. Each PATH is identified by a unique ID.
I need to clip dynamically some of them but the clip-path coordinates should be relative only to that specific PATH. So my idea was to create via JS a dynamic clip-path identified by a specific ID with relative coordinates to that PATH and associate to them.
Let me propose an example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
    width="210mm"
    height="297mm"
    viewBox="0 0 210 297"
    version="1.1"
    id="svg7593"
    xml:space="preserve"
    sodipodi:docname="syn_exp_2.svg"
    inkscape:version="1.2.2 (b0a8486, 2022-12-01)"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><sodipodi:namedview
    id="namedview7595"
    pagecolor="#ffffff"
    bordercolor="#000000"
    borderopacity="0.25"
    inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
    inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
    inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
    inkscape:document-units="mm"
    showgrid="false"
    inkscape:zoom="6.1433221"
    inkscape:cx="51.437967"
    inkscape:cy="116.46793"
    inkscape:window-width="2560"
    inkscape:window-height="1009"
    inkscape:window-x="1920"
    inkscape:window-y="0"
    inkscape:window-maximized="1"
    inkscape:current-layer="light" /><defs
    id="defs7590" /><g
    inkscape:label="Layer 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer1"><g
    id="g67962"
    transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,9.2160546,16.853454)">
<g
    id="frame">
    <rect
    fill="none"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    id="rect67939"
    x="0"
    y="0" />
</g>
<g
    id="shape">
        <path
    fill="#006837"
    d="M 50,97.578 10.807,58.384 V 5.632 l 5.034,-1.458 c 19.153,-5.551 49.162,-5.55 68.318,0 l 5.035,1.458 v 52.752 z"
    id="path67942" />
        <rect
    x="48"
    y="92.792"
    fill="#006837"
    width="4"
    height="7.2080002"
    id="rect67944" />
</g>
<g
    id="dark">
    <path
    fill="#009245"
    d="M 50,97.225 11.057,58.28 V 5.82 l 4.854,-1.406 c 19.114,-5.538 49.062,-5.539 68.179,0 l 4.854,1.406 v 52.46 z"
    id="path67947" />
    <rect
    x="48.25"
    y="92.792"
    fill="#009245"
    width="3.5"
    height="7.2080002"
    id="rect67949" />
</g>
<g
    id="light">
    <path
    fill="#96d48d"
    d="M 50,96.518 11.557,58.073 V 6.195 L 16.05,4.894 c 19.037,-5.515 48.862,-5.515 67.9,0 l 4.494,1.301 v 51.878 z"
    id="path-level"
    clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" />
    <rect
    x="48.75"
    y="92.792"
    fill="#96d48d"
    width="2.5"
    height="7.2080002"
    id="rect67954" />
</g>

    <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
        <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="10%" />
    </clipPath>

</g></g></svg>
```

The clipPath seems is pointing wrong coordinates.
What I need to achieve is to obtain a clipped portion of the PATH object identified by id="path-level" regardles its graphical position in the whole SVG object.

How can I obtain the result?

Comment: It's not the tiny pointy bit at the bottom but it's the whole tank, the light green inside part.

Comment: Do you mean the lightgreen is meant to represent liquid in a tank and you want to display a liquid level?

Comment: yes, correct you are right,
my mistake.
I'd to apply to PATH identified by id="path-level".

Comment: I corrected the code,
please could you have an eye on this now?

Answer (score 0):

Just use objectBoundingBox units. They run from 0 to 1 where 1 is the whole size of the shape being clipped.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
    width="210mm"
    height="297mm"
    viewBox="0 0 210 297"
    version="1.1"
    id="svg7593"
    xml:space="preserve"
    sodipodi:docname="syn_exp_2.svg"
    inkscape:version="1.2.2 (b0a8486, 2022-12-01)"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><sodipodi:namedview
    id="namedview7595"
    pagecolor="#ffffff"
    bordercolor="#000000"
    borderopacity="0.25"
    inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
    inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
    inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
    inkscape:document-units="mm"
    showgrid="false"
    inkscape:zoom="6.1433221"
    inkscape:cx="51.437967"
    inkscape:cy="116.46793"
    inkscape:window-width="2560"
    inkscape:window-height="1009"
    inkscape:window-x="1920"
    inkscape:window-y="0"
    inkscape:window-maximized="1"
    inkscape:current-layer="light" /><defs
    id="defs7590" /><g
    inkscape:label="Layer 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer1"><g
    id="g67962"
    transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,9.2160546,16.853454)">
<g
    id="frame">
    <rect
    fill="none"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    id="rect67939"
    x="0"
    y="0" />
</g>
<g
    id="shape">
        <path
    fill="#006837"
    d="M 50,97.578 10.807,58.384 V 5.632 l 5.034,-1.458 c 19.153,-5.551 49.162,-5.55 68.318,0 l 5.035,1.458 v 52.752 z"
    id="path67942" />
        <rect
    x="48"
    y="92.792"
    fill="#006837"
    width="4"
    height="7.2080002"
    id="rect67944" />
</g>
<g
    id="dark">
    <path
    fill="#009245"
    d="M 50,97.225 11.057,58.28 V 5.82 l 4.854,-1.406 c 19.114,-5.538 49.062,-5.539 68.179,0 l 4.854,1.406 v 52.46 z"
    id="path67947" />
    <rect
    x="48.25"
    y="92.792"
    fill="#009245"
    width="3.5"
    height="7.2080002"
    id="rect67949" />
</g>
<g
    id="light">
    <path
    fill="#96d48d"
    d="M 50,96.518 11.557,58.073 V 6.195 L 16.05,4.894 c 19.037,-5.515 48.862,-5.515 67.9,0 l 4.494,1.301 v 51.878 z"
    id="path-level"
    clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" />
    <rect
    x="48.75"
    y="92.792"
    fill="#96d48d"
    width="2.5"
    height="7.2080002"
    id="rect67954" />
</g>

    <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect width="1" height=".1" />
    </clipPath>

</g></g></svg>
```